# How to run android instrumentation tests sequentially?

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

Do instrumentation tests in android run in parallel or sequentially?
I want to run my android tests sequentially can someone help me how to configure it.

Comment: Are you using `Espresso`? If so, it should be sequentially by default

Comment: Configuration Details:- https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests

Answer (score 0):

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.DEFAULT)

test01() test02() test03()
A0_test() A1_test() A2_test()